# Creating list from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm tasked with creating a list of the values associated with a specific key from a list of dictionaries.

Currently, I'm two for loops and a conditional into this but I know there's a much more efficient way of going about this.

```
#lst = list of dict.

#k = specific key being checked for

for dict in lst:

  for ind in dict:

   if dict[ind] == k:
      ret_val.append(dict[ind])
```

The instructions also state that I am to assume that all dictionaries contain the key and that the value should only be added if the value doesn't already exist.

Comment: Could you give specific inputs and outputs that your function is trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't need to iterate over all the dictionary keys, comparing each to your "needle"/search key -- you can replace the inner `for` loop and subsequent `if` statement with `if k in dict:`  (side note, consider using a different name for your dictionary variable, as using `dict` shadows the `dict` builtin)

Comment: lst = [{red : 2, blue : 3, green :5},{blue : 1, red : 6, green : 4}, etc],  looking for key 'red'        out = [2, 6, etc]

Comment: Also, `ret_val = [d[k] for d in lst if k in d]` or `ret_val = [v for v in (d.get(k) for d in lst) if v is not None]` should both work (making some assumptions here, and note that the latter version is a little more efficient but assumes that `None` isn't a value used in the dictionaries).

Comment: Another option using Walrus operator (to find color k): `[v for d in lst if (v:=d.get(k))]`

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this:

```
ret_val = [dict[ind] for dict in lst for ind in dict if dict[ind]==k]
```